# NextJs App Won't Server Side Render on production with Docker (Linux server)

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, nginx, next.js

I'm trying to deploy this app that is build with Next.js in frontend and the backend is with Laravel

I have these docker files

**app/backend has these files**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    #PHP Service
    timeinkbackend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: timeinkbackend
        container_name: timeinkbackend
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: timeink
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        working_dir: /var/www
        networks:
            - timeinknetwork

    #Nginx Service
    timeinkwebserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: nginx-webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
            - "4435:443"
        environment:
            - NGINX_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./nginx/conf.d/app.sandbox.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx/cloudflare:/etc/nginx/ssl/

            # Uncomment this line if you want to use Let's Encrypt certificates
            # - ./nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            # Uncomment this line if you want to use self-signed certificates
            #- ./nginx/self-signed:/etc/nginx/ssl/
        depends_on:
            - timeinkbackend  
            - timeinkfrontend
        networks:
            - timeinknetwork
            - server_default

    timeinkfrontend:
        container_name: timeinkfrontend
        build:
            context: ../timeink-frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        #ports:
        #   - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            - timeinknetwork
    #MySQL Service
    timeinkdb:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: metag-job-mysql-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: timeink
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql-db
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
            - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
            - timeinknetwork

#Docker Networks
networks:
    timeinknetwork:
        driver: bridge
    server_default:
        external: true

#Volumes
volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official PHP image as the base image
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

# Install Alpine package dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    oniguruma-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Install PHP extensions using docker-php-ext-install
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-xpm \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Change ownership to www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# Install project dependencies using Composer
RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

ngix conf.d

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /gateway/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://timeinkfrontend:3002/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    }
}


server {
    listen 5001;
    server_name localhost;  # Change to your domain or server name

    root /var/www/public;  # Change to the path of your Laravel public directory

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass timeinkbackend:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
}
```

**app/frontend**

Dockerfile

```
# Specify the base image to use
FROM node:18.12.0-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/frontend

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN yarn build

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 3002

# Start the application in production mode
CMD ["yarn", "start", "--port", "3002"]
```

On top of this I have installed nginx proxy manager which will handle the request at 80 port, everything is working fine the only problem I have is with Server Side pages, is not loading them but locally works fine everything. I prod I get this error

```
https://example.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/employee-management/%5Buuid%5D-bacd9a6ff1fc7917.js
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
```

also this is
.env file in front

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL=https://example.com/
BACKEND_URL=https://example.com/gateway/api
SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD=knz78MWeNra3kAMvtC2xKatcLfpTJggD
```

and this is the [uuid].tsx

```
"use-client";
import React from "react";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
// import useSWR from 'swr';
// import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

import Layout from "@/components/Layout";
// import AuthGuard from '@/components/Guards/AuthGuard';
import SingleEmployee from "@/components/Employee/SingleEmployee";
// import LoadingSpinner from '@/components/LoadingSpinner';
// import ErrorComponent from '@/components/ErrorComponent';
import LoadingSpinner from "@/components/LoadingSpinner";
import AuthGuard from "@/components/Guards/AuthGuard";
import ProfileBasedGuard from "@/components/Guards/ProfileBaseGuard";
import { ProfileTypes } from "@/interfaces/user.interface";
import useEmployee from "@/hooks/useEmployee";
// import ProfileBasedGuard from '@/components/Guards/ProfileBaseGuard';

export default function Employee() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState<any>();
  // const { t } = useTranslation(['common', 'employee']);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { uuid } = router.query;

  const { getSingleEmployee } = useEmployee();
  // const { data: userData, mutate: mutateUser, error } = useSWR<any>(`users/${uuid}`);
  console.log("data", userData);
  const fetchdata = async () => {
    const dat = await getSingleEmployee(Number(uuid));
    //  const dat = await getSingleEmployee(uuid)
    console.log("dat", dat);
    setUserData(dat);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchdata();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  if (!userData) {
    return (
      <>
        {uuid}
        {`///users/${uuid}`} <LoadingSpinner />
      </>
    );
  }

  if (!userData?.data) {
    return (
      <p>Employee: </p>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthGuard>
      <ProfileBasedGuard profiles={[ProfileTypes.Admin]}>
        <Layout>
          <SingleEmployee
            employee={userData?.data}
            mutateEmployee={() => fetchdata()}
          />
        </Layout>
      </ProfileBasedGuard>
    </AuthGuard>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }: { locale: any }) => ({
  props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
      "common",
      "validation",
      "employee",
      "login-signup",
      "time-tracking",
    ])),
  },
});
```

I did find something in google related to domain and changing to localhost in .env and stuff like that but still no result. Also if i change for example backend url in .env to localhost:8085/gateway/api, it also break also static pages and cannot communicate with backend